# Using Azure B2C/B2B to secure on-premise web application

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I am looking at a solution to secure on-premise applications using a centralized Identity and Access Management (IAM) solution instead of baking a custom IAM solution. These on-premise application could be deployed across several of our customers globally.

I have looked at using the Azure AD B2C for this purpose but it looks like it can only provide Authentication solution and not Authorization, at least not out of the box. I haven't found a single working sample with does both AuthZ and AuthN. I am also not sure if Azure AD B2C is the solution for implementing a centralized AuthZ and AuthN solution. I have looked at Azure B2B briefly and feel this could be right for our use cases, but it is a bit confusing as to when to choose B2C vs B2B.

I am hoping to get any guidance towards the right approach to have a centralized AuthN and AuthZ solution for on-premise applications.

Answer (score 0):

B2B is for partners, B2C is for customers.

You can get authorisation in the application by the application looking at the claims that are returned.

A better way is to implement [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-identity-protection-overview).

"Control access based on location, groups, and apps.  Conditional Access can also be used to control non-risk based situations. For example, you can require MFA for customers accessing a specific app, or block access from specified geographies."